# Tkinter - Python 3.3 - Problems destroying a window

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am currently writing a basic program in **`tkinter`** and having problems with one specific **window**, known as the "`appetiser`".

A button on a previous screen.

I am really confused with the problem I am having so I have pasted the whole `appetiser` window below. (sorry to just dump it here)

```
#Appetiser Window
def appetiser():
    global app, root


#----------------------------------MEAL-1------------------------
#----------------------------------MEAL-1------------------------
    def PlusMix():
        global MixQuan
        MixQuan = MixQuan + 1
        DisplayButton["text"]=str(MixQuan)

    def NegMix():
        global MixQuan
        MixQuan = MixQuan - 1
        DisplayButton["text"]=str(MixQuan)

    Label(app, text = "", width = 65, height = 5).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = N)

    Label(app,text = "Mixed Starter", font = ("roboto", 20)).grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

    DisplayButton = Button(app, text = MixQuan, bg="magenta")
    DisplayButton.grid(column = 3, row = 2, sticky = W)
    DisplayButton.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Plus1Button = Button(app, text = "+1", command=PlusMix, bg="magenta")
    Plus1Button.grid(column = 4, row = 2, sticky = W)
    Plus1Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Neg1Button = Button(app, text = "-1", command=NegMix, bg="magenta")
    Neg1Button.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = W)
    Neg1Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )
#----------------------------------MEAL-2-------------------------
#----------------------------------MEAL-2-------------------------

    def PlusDuck():
        global DuckQuan
        DuckQuan = DuckQuan + 1 
        Display2Button["text"]=str(DuckQuan)

    def NegDuck():
        global DuckQuan
        DuckQuan = DuckQuan - 1 
        Display2Button["text"]=str(DuckQuan)



    Label(app,text = "Crispy Duck", font = ("roboto", 20)).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)


    Display2Button = Button(app, text = DuckQuan, bg="magenta")
    Display2Button.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = W)
    Display2Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Plus2Button = Button(app, text = "+1", command=PlusDuck, bg="magenta")
    Plus2Button.grid(column = 4, row = 3, sticky = W)
    Plus2Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Neg2Button = Button(app, text = "-1", command=NegDuck, bg="magenta")
    Neg2Button.grid(column = 2, row = 3, sticky = W)
    Neg2Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

#----------------------------------MEAL-3---------------------------
#----------------------------------MEAL-3---------------------------

    def plus3():
        global LambQuan
        LambQuan = LambQuan + 1 
        Display3Button["text"]=str(LambQuan)

    def neg3():
        global LambQuan
        LambQuan = LambQuan - 1 
        Display3Button["text"]=str(LambQuan)

    Label(app,text = "Lamb starter", font = ("roboto", 20)).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

    Display3Button = Button(app, text = LambQuan, bg="magenta")
    Display3Button.grid(column = 3, row = 4, sticky = W)
    Display3Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Plus3Button = Button(app, text = "+1", command=plus3, bg="magenta")
    Plus3Button.grid(column = 4, row = 4, sticky = W)
    Plus3Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

    Neg3Button = Button(app, text = "-1", command=neg3, bg="magenta")
    Neg3Button.grid(column = 2, row = 4, sticky = W)
    Neg3Button.config(height = 10, width = 10 )

#----------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------

    BackButton = Button(app, text = "Back", command=OpenMain, bg="magenta")
    BackButton.grid(column = 2, row = 5, sticky = W)
    BackButton.config(height = 10, width = 10 )


    FinishButton = Button(app, text = "Finish", command=OpenFinish, bg="magenta")
    FinishButton.grid(column = 4, row = 5, sticky = W)
    FinishButton.config(height = 10, width = 10 )


    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()

    Label(app, text = "", width = 75, height = 20).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = N)

    root.mainloop()
```

### Now

the 2 functions **`OpenMain()`** and **`OpenWindow()`** are called from other windows to return to previous screens but they work fine when being called in other windows.

I am only having problems calling the functions from this window from "**[`FinishButton`]**" and "**[`BackButton`]**".

Below are the 2 functions which have been previously called and work fine.

```
#Wipe window and open main
def OpenMain():
    global app, root
    app.destroy()
    app = Frame(root) 
    app.grid()
    main()

#Wipe appetiser window and draw finish window
def OpenFinish():   
    global app, root
    app.destroy()
    app = Frame(root) 
    app.grid()
    FinishWindow()
```

When the `OpenFinish()` function is called, the "`appetiser`" **window**, is not destroyed and the main **window** is created directly under the `appetiser` **window**.

Like I said, sorry for just dumping my code here, but I just cant figure out the problem.

The functions work just fine in other windows, and I've followed the same format for creating windows for the rest of the program.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Too much code to read.  Try to make something much smaller that exhibits the problem.

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a MCVE ( a **Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code** ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: Where in your code do you actually call `appetiser`? I don't see it. Also, it seems like you are creating a lot of widgets that are a child of `app` before you ever define `app`. Is your indentation correct?

Answer (score -1):

1. **Avoid `global`**-s
2. **Design** in object- / Class-based manner
3. **Compose** objects & **manage** their alignment & **control** their content strictly inside a Tkinter-based hiearachy of `.Tk()`/`.Toplevel()`/`.Frame()` "containers"
4. **Avoid** self-destructive practice to equip a **`.Button()`** with a power to commit suiccide by `.destroy()` + assignment to `self`

---

```
#  <appetiser> is not a window, it is a procedure ( a segment of code )
#
def appetiser():
    global app, root
    ...
    BackButton   = Button( app,
                           text    = "Back",
                           command = OpenMain,             # --> app.destroy()-->
                           bg      = "magenta"
                           )
    ...
    FinishButton = Button( app,
                           text    = "Finish",
                           command = OpenFinish,           # --> app.destroy()-->
                           bg      = "magenta"
                           )
    ...
# -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- |
#                                                                               v
def OpenMain():
    global app, root
    app.destroy()                                          # <-- COMMIT SUICCIDE
    app = Frame( root )                                    # new Frame instance
    app.grid()
    ...

def OpenFinish():   
    global app, root
    app.destroy()                                          # <-- COMMIT SUICCIDE
    app = Frame( root )                                    # new Frame instance
    ...
```